# Adding a number to be displayed as float format with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to add an amount to show up as `1.00` but instead it shows up as `1`. I have tried using `toFixed(2)` with a + 1, but it just stays at `0.00`. Is there a correct way of doing this, perhaps using regex?

```js
var ex = "/^[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$/";

$("#addDollar").on("click", function() {
  var valueOut = $("#totalAmountIn");
  valueOut.val(parseFloat(valueOut.val() + 1).toFixed(2));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Total Amount In</h1>

<input type="text" value="0.00" id="totalAmountIn"></input>

<div class="col-md-4">
  <button type="button" id="addDollar" class="btn btn-default">
  Add Dollar
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse the value before adding 1. Your code is concatenating 1 and then parsing. So `0.00` becomes `0.001`, and when you print that with 2 decimal places it becomes `0.00` again.

```js
var ex = "/^[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$/";

$("#addDollar").on("click", function() {
  var valueOut = $("#totalAmountIn");
  valueOut.val((parseFloat(valueOut.val()) + 1).toFixed(2));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Total Amount In</h1>

<input type="text" value="0.00" id="totalAmountIn"></input>

<div class="col-md-4">
  <button type="button" id="addDollar" class="btn btn-default">
  Add Dollar
  </button>
</div>
```

```js
var ex = "/^[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$/";

$("#addDollar").on("click", function() {
  var valueOut = $("#totalAmountIn");
  valueOut.val((parseFloat(valueOut.val()) + .25).toFixed(2));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Total Amount In</h1>

<input type="text" value="0.00" id="totalAmountIn"></input>

<div class="col-md-4">
  <button type="button" id="addDollar" class="btn btn-default">
  Add $0.25
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, that was interesting.

Comment: What if I wanted to do something like `+ 0.25`? I tried this, `$value.val((parseFloat($value.val()) + .25).toFixed(2));` but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Works fine for me. I added a second snippet showing that.